# Struct forward declaration error: Typedef redefinition with different types

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration

I want to forward declare a struct in the header file.

```
struct GLFWvidmode;

class DesktopVideoMode {
private:
    const GLFWvidmode *videomode;
public:
    DesktopVideoMode(const GLFWvidmode *videomode);
...
```

In the cpp file I include the external header with the definition...

```
#include "DesktopVideoMode.hpp"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

...where the error "*Typedef redefinition with different types ('struct GLFWvidmode' vs 'GLFWvidmode')*" happens:

```
typedef struct
{
    /*! The width, in screen coordinates, of the video mode.
     */
    int width;
    /*! The height, in screen coordinates, of the video mode.
     */
    int height;
    /*! The bit depth of the red channel of the video mode.
     */
    int redBits;
    /*! The bit depth of the green channel of the video mode.
     */
    int greenBits;
    /*! The bit depth of the blue channel of the video mode.
     */
    int blueBits;
    /*! The refresh rate, in Hz, of the video mode.
     */
    int refreshRate;
} GLFWvidmode;
```

Can't I forward declare in a case like this?

Comment: yes, i realized that after i posted the comment and erased it since.

Comment: @AdamS: Then you cannot avoid including the header...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`GLFWvidmode` is not a struct, it's a typedef. You can't forward-declare a typedef. Whoever chose to use an unnamed struct made a poor design decision.

Comment: I was able to change the external header so all occurrences of typedef structs are legit structs, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to mention that `GLFWvidmode` is a typedef name to anonymous struct.. if you purposefully want to forward declare the struct then you should always add a nametag to the struct while declaring the structure as:

```
    typedef struct tagname1{
    some members...;
    }tagname2;
```

note dat `tagname1` and `tagname2` can be same (you can use `tagname1` or `tagname` or `GLFWvidmode`  in both the places)..  and now since the struct is now having a tagname(it's not anonymous anymore) you can reference it for forward declaration.

and **yes** an anonymous struct can't be used for forward declaration as there is no tagname to reference to.. :) hope it helps.