# Typedef Redefinition error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I was working with JNI on Android and I was attempting to do something like:

**Foo.h**:

```
class jobject; //error here!

class Foo {
void dowork(const jobject&);
}
```

**Foo.cpp**:

```
#include <jni.h>
:
:
Foo::dowork(const jobject& obj)
{
   //Do something
}
```

I see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501993/struct-forward-declaration-error-typedef-redefinition-with-different-types) has something similar but I fee that mine is a different case. I don't have a typedef on anonymous structs  but on named structs.  If we see the file [**jni.h**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/master/include/nativehelper/jni.h#62)

```
typedef _jobject*       jobject;
```

and [**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libnativehelper/+/master/include/nativehelper/jni.h#47):

```
class _jobject {};
```

Comment: So where _exactly_ do you get this error? I don't see any `typedef` here.

Comment: `do` is a keyword. Is this actually accepted by the compiler?

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

You are basically doing this:

```
typedef int* Foo;   // typedefing Foo to int*

class Foo           // attempt to declare a class with a name already used for typedef
{
};
```

Comment: So There is no way to do something like what I am attempting, given of course that I can't modify the JNI headers?