# Forward declaration of anonymous typedef struct C++

Tags: c++, struct, forward-declaration, matlab-coder

I have a C++ dll with a header file that is refrencing some generated (Matlab coder) anonymous structs. I am trying to forward declare theese structs in order to avoid including more than the main .h file from my DLL in a new project.

I have seen that [some would deem it impossible to forward declare a struct without a name and just tell me to name my structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18661515/3407324), but in my case I am not in control of how matlab has generated my structs. Hence i venture to ask the question once more.

Would there be a way to forward declare the enclosed struct without changing it's origin?

Sample struct from the generated file I cannot change and don't want to include in my header:

```
typedef struct {
  real_T V_n[21];                     
  real_T ROP;                          
} ExtY_CMSim_T;
```

DLL Header:

```
// Forward Declarations: 
typedef struct ExtY_Sim_T;

extern "C" {
extern __declspec(dllexport) void getOutputs(ExtY_Sim_T &output);
}
```

When compiling the last code snippet, I am told that 'ExtY_Sim_T' has allready been declared as a typedef.

Comment: The generated file is C, not C++. Try putting the forward declaration inside `extern "C" { ... }`.

Comment: The generated file is C, not C++. Use a C compiler, not a C++ compiler for object files that need to use these definitions.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the forward declaration inside extern "C" {...} moved me one step further. 

But I get the following two compile time messages: 
"warning C4091: 'typedef ': ignored on left of 'ExtY_CMSim_T' when no variable is declared" and "error C2371: 'ExtY_Sim_T': redefinition; different basic types"

Answer (score 2):

One option is to tell MATLAB Coder to import the type definition from a header file that you provide. coder.cstructname with the `extern` and `HeaderFile` arguments achieves this: `coder.cstructname(structVariable, 'extern', 'HeaderFile', 'myHeader.h')`

Then you could have the declaration in `myHeader.h` and use the forward declaration as desired.

We've also made internal notes of your requests so we can consider them for future versions of MATLAB Coder.